# Cannot access any network shares from Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares

I host some network shares via samba on an Ubuntu server, for my local network, and I'm not able to access it. Originally I assumed it was a problem with the samba server, but after trying many things, and searches all leading to dead ends, I eventually tried using a different machine (I know I should have done that sooner). I was able to access the Ubuntu network shares from Windows 10 Pro running in a VM (on the computer that can't access anything), this install is like-new, the only thing I ever used it for was the print server management, I never changed *any* settings. Accessing my shares from the VM worked instantly. I also had tried an Ubuntu VM before this and it worked as well. Just to be sure, I borrowed a family members Windows 10 laptop, which while definitely not new, has never had any major settings changed relating to networking (or probably any for that matter), and it also worked perfectly and right away.

So, clearly the problem is with my machine. And I have done several modifications in the past, including registry tweaks when I was testing various servers, so I'm fairly certain I caused whatever this problem is. But that doesn't change the fact that there is a problem, and I have done all I can think of short of posting on a forum, to try and fix the problem. And that brings us here!

I have done extensive searching and troubleshooting on this. Oh and just so we're on the same page, the samba server is setup to ONLY accept SMB v3. I bring this up, because I do appear to have a problem with SMB v1 and/or v2, but considering the server uses 3, hopefully that won't even matter. Also before anyone suggests using a Windows restore to go back to a time where this problem wasn't occurring, unfortunately that won't be possible. I do have restore points setup to automatically be created, however this problem technically surfaced a while ago, but if memory serves me correct, I was satisfied with other network users being able to access the server so I didn't bother trying to fix my own client (after at least 1 or 2 searches online), since it wasn't important to me I guess.

I consider myself a "power-user", but there are times when you just have to accept that you don't know what you're doing, and ask for help.

Also, here's what I see when I try to connect to any PC from the Network tab(?) in Explorer:

```
\\MATTHEW is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource.
Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
The network is not present or not started
```

(MATTHEW is the hostname of the samba server, but I get this message with any shares, Windows or otherwise)

Edit: I finally bit the bullet, and used Windows' Refresh feature to reset my apps and settings, and the issue is gone. Still disappointed the issue was never resolved in a nicer way.

Comment: Could you try "Turn Windows features on or off" in search and enable all SMB options there are. They are  enabled by default but some update actually disabled them

Comment: @Myszsoda I did try that, and it did not change anything, however I don't use SMB v1, which is what those "features" are for.

Comment: Actually, under these options are hidden SMBv2/3 by https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3. Do your "Advanced sharing settings" allowed that and you are not blocked by firewall?

Comment: @Myszsoda I've already verified Smb2 is enabled via this method (and did it again just to make sure). I also tried `select *Smb3*` and there was nothing in the output with Smb3 in it, which I find interesting. And ignoring the fact that this worked in the past, I see no reason the firewall would interfere since it worked fine with the Virtual Machines (which were running on the same Windows 10 machine that currently isn't working).

Edit: Read the documentation again, and it appears that enabling SmbV2 also enables SmbV3 so yes they are both enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I know your issue was posted 2 years ago, but I was also receiving the same error:

> \\SERVER is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource.
> Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
>
> **The network is not present or not started.**

I looked into it for a couple of hours and finally discovered it was because I had stopped the "Workstation" service in Windows and set it to only start manually. To solve it I:

1. Ran `services.msc` and then started the "Workstation" service
2. I made sure that my network adapter had "Client for Microsoft Networks" enabled, which it usually is by default
3. Connected to the server's IP address rather than it's name, e.g. `\\10.0.0.10`

That solved my problem.

Perhaps that may assist someone else out there.